# Creating ArcGlobe annotation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, annotation, arcglobe

I want to put some labels on a globe in ArcGlobe.  I've spent time looking here : http://resources.arcgis.com  and here http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html

However, I can't seem to find any solid examples.

I've looked in the ArcGIS Snippet Finder when using Visual Studio as well.  Also tried looking in the examples that include source code.

Is there somewhere else to look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00q80000010r000000.htm

convert labels into annotation
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Displaying_annotation_features_in_ArcGlobe/00q800000022000000/

To display annotation feature layers as billboarded text, do the following:
Steps:

1. Right-click the annotation feature layer in the table of contents and click Properties.
2. Click the Globe Display tab.
3. Uncheck Rasterize feature layer.
4. Click OK.